# get a particular row in R to a new table

Tags: regex, r

i am new to R so please guide me with this.

Below shown is a simple table called `Order`.

```
   Col1   Col2    Col3

  hey    hi   july 12,2013
  hey    hi   june 12,2013
  hey    hi   April 12,2013
  hey    hi   April 14,2012
```

If i want to write a query such that i get this as result in a new table **ie.** i need to use regular expression to match for a part of string in `Col3` and then count.

```
 july     june   April
  1         1      2
```

please help me if anyone knows how to do it.

Comment: Hmm where did you get stuck when trying this?

Comment: Instead of `regexp` how about doing a count by `month` , i.e. using Date functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` to extract the months' names and `table` to count the frequencies:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Col1   Col2    Col3
hey    hi   'july 12,2013'
hey    hi   'june 12,2013'
hey    hi   'April 12,2013'
hey    hi   'April 14,2012'", header = TRUE)

table(sub("^(\\w+) .*", "\\1", dat$Col3))

# April  july  june 
#     2     1     1
```

---

How does `sub("^(\\w+) .*", "\\1", dat$Col3)` work?

The function `sub` performs replacements in strings. The strings inside quotes are regular expressions. `^` is the beginning of the string, `\\w` is a word character, `+` means one or multiple.  is a literal space. `.*` means any number of any character. The parentheses are used to create a group. The first (and only) group `(\\w+)` matches word characters at the beginning of the string. The second argument in the `sub` function, `"\\1"` is used to replace the whole string with the substring representing the first group. In short: the whole string is replaced by the first word.

Comment: Thnx, can you please explain this sub("^(\\w+) .*", "\\1", dat$Col3) ?

Comment: @Magic I added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Data:

```
data <- read.table(text = "Col1   Col2    Col3
hey    hi   'july 12,2013'
hey    hi   'june 12,2013'
hey    hi   'April 12,2013'
hey    hi   'April 14,2012'", header = TRUE)
```

An answer using dates:

```
    #tranform data in POSIXlt    
    data$Col3 <- as.POSIXlt(data$Col3, format="%B %d, %Y")

    ## group using table with POSIXlt numbers (0 is january)
    table(data$Col3$mon)
    3 5 6 
    2 1 1 

    ## group using table with normal month numbers
    table(month(data$Col3))
    4 6 7 
    2 1 1

    ## group using aggregate with POSIXlt numbers (0 is january) 
    aggregate(data$Col1, by=list(data[,"Col3"]$mon), length)

    #result
    Group.1 x
    1       3 2
    2       5 1
    3       6 1

    ## group using aggregate with normal month numbers 
    aggregate(data$Col1, by=list(month(data$Col3)), length)

    #result
  Group.1 x
1       4 2
2       6 1
3       7 1
```

PS: whe you get data$Col3$mon in POSIXlt january is 0, so april is 3 and not 4 as you would expect. To get "normal" month numbers you should use month(data$Col3) - just realised that reading Ananda's comment.

If you want a prettier version (by Ananda Mahto):

```
    Col3 <- as.POSIXlt(data$Col3, format="%B %d, %Y"); table(month.name[month(Col3)])

    April  July  June 
      2     1     1
```

Comment: This is much prettier (and we don't have to remember about the different origin of POSIXlt): `Col3 <- as.POSIXlt(data$Col3, format="%B %d, %Y"); table(month.name[month(Col3)])`

Comment: Just added the difference between Col3$mon and month(Col3) too, did not know about that, thanks for the comment.